# Shell script sorting

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell

I am trying to write a shell script that inserts data in postgres:

First Part:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in /folder/*.sql; do
  psql -U postgres -f $f
done

for f in /folder1/*.sql; do
  psql -U postgres -f $f
done
```

I need to add several conditions on it.

1. I need to sort file names for folder.
   Example my folder has files a.sql, c.sql, b.sql

I want to sort them on basis of name so first a.sql should be inserted then b.sql and then c.sql.

2. For folder1 there exists some unwanted files, i want to ignore them(which is happening now also) and first i want to insert the files having base fields and then other tables.

Example folder1 has 1.sql, a.txt, 3.sql, base.sql.

I do not want to insert a.txt
And first base.sql should be inserted and then 1.sql and 3.sql

How to do it via shell script?

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk wildcard expands to a sorted list, so you can just use one loop:

```sh
for f in /folder/*.sql /folder1/base.sql /folder1/?.sql; do
  psql -U postgres -f $f
done
```

The list is sorted alphabetically, though, and depends on the locale.

The question mark matches just one  character, so `?.sql` will match both 1.sql and 3.sql. You can also use `[0-9]*.sql` to match files whose names start with a digit. Under extended globbing (`shopt -s extglob`), you can even say `+([0-9]).sql`, so it also matches files with more than one digit (e.g. 124.sql). Note that asciibetically, 10 < 2.

Comment: Thanks.If i want to insert all the files except the files that have word - sort in them. 

And all the files that have word match in them.

Comment: What would be the regex?

Comment: @EatPayBong: Under `extglob`, you can use `!(word).sql` to match everything but `word.sql`.